# 429 error trying to hit an API from within an Azure Data Factory For Each activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

We're trying to put together a proof-of-concept where we read data from an API and store it in a blob.  We have a For Each activity that loops through a file that has parameters that are used in an API call.  We are trying to do this in parallel.  The first API call works fine, but the second call returns a 429 error.  Are we asking the impossible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually error code 429 meaning is too many requests. Inside ForEach activity, use Sequence execution option and see if that helps.